# Scraping from a page where the value is a selection fro a drop down menu

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have following html code:

```html
<div class="6u">
                <select name="PropertyId" tabindex="13">
        <option value='0'>Select Property</option>
        <option value='190' >Alderton Crescent</option>
        <option value='9' >Cambridge Way</option>
        <option value='11' selected>Corney Avenue</option>
        <option value='8' >Stanley Gardens</option>                                      
    </select>
</div>
```

I am trying to extract only the selected option- in this case Corney Avenue.
the code which i'm using:

```
soup.find('select', {'name': 'PropertyId'}).find_all({'option': 'selected'})
```

returns almost the same but into kind of a list:

```
[<option value="0">Select Property</option>
<option value='0'>Select Property</option>
<option value='190' >Alderton Crescent</option>
<option value='9' >Cambridge Way</option>
<option value='11' selected>Corney Avenue</option>
<option value='8' >Stanley Gardens</option>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""<div class="6u">
                <select name="PropertyId" tabindex="13">
        <option value='0'>Select Property</option>
        <option value='190' >Alderton Crescent</option>
        <option value='9' >Cambridge Way</option>
        <option value='11' selected>Corney Avenue</option>
        <option value='8' >Stanley Gardens</option>                                      
    </select>
</div>"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

#find the select tag
select=soup.find('select',attrs={'name':'PropertyId'})

#find option value in select tag where 'selected' attribute is present
value=select.find('option',attrs={'selected':True})

print(value.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternativ approach could be to use the `css selector` in combination with `.text` / `get_text()` - Following line will grab `<option>` that is `selected` and part of `<select>` named "PropertyId":

```
soup.select_one('select[name="PropertyId"] option:checked').text
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<div class="6u">
                <select name="PropertyId" tabindex="13">
        <option value='0'>Select Property</option>
        <option value='190' >Alderton Crescent</option>
        <option value='9' >Cambridge Way</option>
        <option value='11' selected>Corney Avenue</option>
        <option value='8' >Stanley Gardens</option>                                      
    </select>
</div>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

soup.select_one('select[name="PropertyId"] option:checked').text
```

#### Output

```
Corney Avenue
```